# add sound to swipe gesture recognizer

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to make a sound play whenever a user swipes forward or back.

I've already added sounds to all of my `UIButton`s with `IBAction`s that play the sounds when the buttons are pressed, and it works no problem. But, when I try to do the same thing with a swipe gesture, it doesn't work. The swipe gesture is created in the storyboard and the swiping works fine, but when I try to hook the gesture recognizer up to an IBAction that specifies that the sound should play, it still swipes but there's no sound. Is there a different way that I should be implementing this instead of with IBActions?

edit: Upon further investigation it looks like the method that I'm hooking up to the swipe gesture recognizer is never getting called, despite it saying it's connected to it when I ctrl+click the gesture recognizer in the storyboard. I have methods connected to my right swipes no problem, but I can't seem to get one to connect to the left swipe properly so that the method gets called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never managed to figure out why the method attached to the swipe wasn't getting called but I just made it so that the desired sound was called in viewDidLoad of the page being swiped to; not a perfect solution but it gets the job done and it sounds just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try playing the sound either on the main thread, or after a delay. Trying to play a sound while on an event thread might be causing some issues. Try one code A or B and let me know what happens:

Code A:

```
- (void)playAudioOnSwipe {
    // Play the audio here
}

- (IBAction) onSwipe {
    [self performSelector:@selector(playAudioOnSwipe) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];
}
```

Code B:

```
- (void)playAudioOnSwipe {
    // Play the audio here
}

- (IBAction) onSwipe {
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(playAudioOnSwipe) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
}
```

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint on the function that handles the swipe to make sure it's actually getting called from the swipe action?

Comment: I didn't do that exactly but I did put an NSLog to see if it was getting called, and like I said in my edit it wasn't. I figured out a workaround that gets the job done though.